# OpenCV VideoWriter writes corrupted video files

Tags: python, macos, opencv, video-streaming

I am trying to stream and save video from my webcam with the Python script shown below but, for some reason, the 'myvideo.mp4' file has a very small size and cannot be opened with QuickTime (or other players) - it seems to be empty. However, the video stream works perfectly.

As suggested in other topics, I have tried different file formats and codecs and I pass exact fps, width and height that my webcam returns. Perhaps anyone knows what can be the issue here? Thanks in advance!

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

writer = cv2.VideoWriter('myvideo.mp4',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'),fps,(width,height))

while True:

    ret,frame = cap.read()

    # OPERATIONS (DRAWING)
    writer.write(frame)    
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
writer.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have also tried running the script as superuser but it did not help. I am using Mac.

QuickTime error:

*The document “myvideo.mp4” could not be opened.
The file isn’t compatible with QuickTime Player.*

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/takuma7/44f9ecb028ff00e2132e) is a list of codecs. But I had no luck with them tbh.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change fourcc(4-character code of codec used to compress the frames.)

```
writer = cv2.VideoWriter('myvideo.mp4',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'),fps,(width,height))
```

replace it with

```
writer = cv2.VideoWriter('myvideo.mp4',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'),fps,(width,height))
```

Comment: This is the first codec that I tried but with it there is an error: OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x44495658/'XVID' is not supported with codec id 12 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'

Comment: umm, try to remain the file as myvideo.avi.

Answer (score 0):

## Simply fix typo

Change

```py
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
```

to

```py
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
```

You were taking `CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH` twice.

## If the problem persists...

If this still does not help, try to swap them. It seems stupid, but helped for me. I guess that the `get` method somehow takes orientation into account, but then reading a frame neglects the orientation of the video (or opposite, does not matter, they are just inconsistent). I had exactly the same problem, and swapped width with height and it solved it.

## Extra

A bit old [list of codecs](https://gist.github.com/takuma7/44f9ecb028ff00e2132e) tested on mac.